# ActiveAdmin actions testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, activeadmin

I have ActiveAdmin controller for actions with some database objects.

```
ActiveAdmin.register MyObject do
```

In that file I got an action, which uses some parameters and creates a file:

```
collection_action :some_method_name, method: :get do
```

What is a proper way to create a RSpec spec for that action which will pass some parameters and perform checks in resulting file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Admin::MyObjectsController do
  describe "#some_method_name" do
    it "does some stuff" do
      params = {a: 1, b: 2}
      get :some_method_name, params
      expect(response).to be_success
    end 
  end
end
```